# Is it possible to shuffle paragraphs?

Tags: text-editing, paragraphs

I'd like to be able to quickly "shuffle" the order in which all paragraphs in a region occur. Can this be easily accomplished in emacs?

For example, consider the following region.

```
Hello world.

This is the original second paragraph
and it contains two lines.

This is the original third paragraph and
it contains three
lines

Paragraph number four.
```

Running my desired command would result in a random reordering of these four paragraphs. The output might be something like

```
This is the original third paragraph and
it contains three
lines

Hello world.

Paragraph number four.

This is the original second paragraph
and it contains two lines.
```

Comment: How about `randomize-region.el`?:  https://www.mail-archive.com/gnu-emacs-sources@gnu.org/msg00034.html which is the accepted answer from this related thread:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172054/how-can-i-random-sort-lines-in-a-buffer

Comment: @lawlist `randomize-region.el` is related, but doesn't solve the problem. `randomize-region` permutes all of the lines and doesn't respect paragraphs. I'm sure the code can be altered, but I'm not savvy enough to see how.

Comment: @lawlist Actually... maybe I am savvy enough. I think all I need is to change `(insert (concat str "\n"))))))` to `(insert (concat str "\n\n"))))))`.

Comment: Yes, its true we can shuffle paragraphs by using this tool they provide reverse line shuffle, Sort Line Alphabetically, shuffle paragraphs that tool address is: [https://nadiakvk.org/shuffle-paragraphs/](https://nadiakvk.org/shuffle-paragraphs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted from `sort-paragraphs`:

```
(defun sort-paragraphs-randomly (beg end)
  (interactive (if (use-region-p)
                   (list (region-beginning) (region-end))
                 (list (point-min) (point-max))))
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (narrow-to-region beg end)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (sort-subr nil
                 (lambda ()
                   (while (and (not (eobp)) (looking-at paragraph-separate))
                     (forward-line 1)))
      'forward-paragraph
      nil nil 
      (lambda (_ _)
        (= (random 2) 0))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Edt.
For short answer,
look at @lawlist answer.

For explicit one,
kinda. you may repeat the following sequence

```
(mark-paragraph)
(kill-region)
(backward-paragraph) || (forward-paragraph)
(yank)
```

while if in the leaf or root paragraph and there is no newline at the beginning and end do

```
(backward-paragraph) || (forward-paragraph)     ;; Respectively (leaf || root)
(newline)
```

Ow.. and if this happened to be the leaf then also do

```
(previous-line)
```

Answer (score 1):

First create a list of paragraphs in the region. Then 1. shuffle the list, 2. delete the region, and 3. insert the shuffled list. The function below is a modified version of the `shuffle-list` function found [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/gnu-emacs-sources@gnu.org/msg00034.html) (thanks to lawlist for the link). Also, to get the correct spacing between paragraphs, you have to start with the cursor on the line *above* the first paragraph and end on the line *below* the last paragraph.

```el
(defun shuffle (list)
  (let ((i (1- (length list))))
    (while (>= i 0)
      (let ((rand (random (1+ i)))
            (orig (nth i list)))
        (setcar (nthcdr i list) (nth rand list))
        (setcar (nthcdr rand list) orig)
        (setq i (1- i)))))
  list)

(defun shuffle-paragraphs (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (let* ((region (buffer-substring beg end))
         (list (split-string region org-element-paragraph-separate t))
         (shuffle (shuffle list)))
    (delete-region beg end)
    (cl-loop for par in shuffle
             do (insert par))))
```